# Are the two starters for Pokémon Colosseum always exactly the same at start?

Tags: pokemon-colosseum

I know this is an old game, but in the GameCube game *[Pokémon Colosseum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Colosseum)*, you start off with an Umbreon and an Espeon. Do they always have the same natures and starting stats for each new game? I know they are always boys. I would guess yes for stats, but are the natures random?

The reason this information would be useful is for trying to spawn favorable natures in those two Pokémon if they are indeed random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbreon is Lv. 26 and Espeon is Level 25. Espeon is stronger overall, while Umbreon has more health and defenses, but weaker offensive stats. They also start out with different attacks as well.

In order to prevent breeding either of these two, Espeon
and Umbreon will always be male. Their IVs and Nature, however, will be
random.

Comment: I found the source here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/914973-pokemon-colosseum/faqs/29532